# Double query a table from two fields (INNER JOIN?)

Tags: mysql

I hope I can explain myself.

I have a many to many table (asignaciones) which points to alumnos and invest tables. Both of those tables has a institucionID which points to instituciones table.

I need to get (in one query) both instituciones from alumnos and invest.  I have this but is not complete. I guess if because of the AND in the last inner join:

```
SELECT
alumnos.alumnosID,
invest.investigadoresID,
asignaciones.alumnosID AS alumnosID1,
asignaciones.investigadoresID AS investigadoresID1,
instituciones.institucion
FROM alumnos
INNER JOIN asignaciones ON alumnos.alumnosID = asignaciones.alumnosID
INNER JOIN invest ON asignaciones.investigadoresID = invest.investigadoresID
INNER JOIN instituciones ON alumnos.institucionesID = instituciones.institucionesID AND invest.institucionesID = instituciones.institucionesID
```

This lacks the second institucion. I am getting just one

Any hints on this is really appreciated

Comment: Can you add sqlfiddle link to your question so that we can try with the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query schold solve your problem:

```
SELECT
alumnos.alumnosID,
invest.investigadoresID,
asignaciones.alumnosID AS alumnosID1,
asignaciones.investigadoresID AS investigadoresID1,
instituciones.institucion
instituciones1.institucion
FROM alumnos
INNER JOIN asignaciones ON alumnos.alumnosID = asignaciones.alumnosID
INNER JOIN invest ON asignaciones.investigadoresID = invest.investigadoresID
INNER JOIN instituciones instituciones ON alumnos.institucionesID = instituciones.institucionesID 
INNER JOIN instituciones instituciones1 ON  invest.institucionesID = instituciones1.institucionesID
```

You have to join the last table twice.

Comment: You should give aliases to the two `institucion` columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question:  WHat is this? INNER JOIN instituciones instituciones1 ON   ... 2 tables in the inner join?

Comment: @notuo `instituciones1`  is an alias for the tabe `instituciones`. So the sql engine knows from which table the values comes. if you not use an alias, the sql engine can not decides this. Hope this helps.